# Edit product with get url parameter

Tags: php, pdo

To edit the product, I send the product id with the get parameter as in the example below.

```
     <a class="flex justify-center" href="<?=admin_url('edit-product?id=')?><?=$products['id']?>">
```

But when I click on the link, it directs me to the index page, not the edit-product page.
Is this problem related to the route system or is there an error that I cannot see? I'll be happy if you can help me.

I make a check on the product editing page as below, and then I try to pull the product contents.

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id'])) {
    echo 'ürün bulunamadı.';
}

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = ?');
$query->execute([
    $_GET['id']
]);
$product = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The admin route system I use

```
<?php

function admin_controller($controllerName){
    $controllerName = strtolower($controllerName);
    return PATH . '/admin/controller/' . $controllerName . '.php';
}

function admin_view($viewName){
    return PATH . '/admin/view/' . $viewName . '.php';
}

function admin_url($url = false)
{
    return URL . '/admin/' . $url;
}
function admin_public_url($url = false)
{
    return URL . '/admin/public/' . $url;
}
```

Comment: _"Is this problem related to the route system"_ - We can't possibly answer that without knowing how you handle routing. We don't know _anything_ about your application except from what you've posted here. What's `admin_url()`? What argument does it expect? A key/slug or a URL? You could try and add the query param after: `<?= admin_url('edit-product')?>?id=<?= $products['id'] ?>`. Check what the URL in the href actually looks like in the HTML in the brower (right click on the page and "view source"). Are you using some CMS or framework?

Comment: Also unrelated to current issue but your probably want `fetch` not `fetchAll`, if there is only 1 product.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I First of all, thank you for your answer, I added my admin route system by editing my question. I am not using any framework or cms system now, I am trying to install my own mvc production.

Comment: @user3783243 Thanks for helping, can you make suggestions to improve my route system? I'm just learning php now and the suggestions are very important to me.

Comment: What you've posted isn't really a "routing system". It's just some helper functions for creating URL's. A router is what receives the request, checks the URL and executes the configured controller (the C in MVC) for that URL. To use a router, you should also use the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) (all page requests gets sent to your index.php-file, which then executes the router.) So you should never need to add `.php` to the URL's since you're not actually calling different PHP files difrectly.

Comment: I would recommend using one of the many existing [routing libraries](https://packagist.org/?query=router) instead of trying to roll your own. Even if you want to build your own MVC framework, it's better to use tried and tested components in it instead of trying to reinvent all the wheels (unless it's for learning purposes, but then you should focus on one component at the time and really learn them fully)

Comment: As far as I understand, it is impossible to operate with the get parameter in this routing process, but this is a project I started and a project that is almost completely finished, do you have an extra solution?